# Map application similar to Windows 10 maps using Template10

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp, template10

I want to design my map application using template 10 but the problem is i am using webview and want search and directons results on same page when splitview search button or directions button is clicked similar to Windows 10 maps app i dont want a master details page structure how to acheive this using template10

Edit 1:
Sorry for not being clear.I don't want search or direction on other page but on the same map page as a flyout same as in windows 10 maps.
How split view handles navigation and how back button is handled.Is it a page or a user control.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you using WebView or not? Template10 is C# and not for web projects. Do you have any code you can show us?

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting has already been demonstrated in the Search (and Login) project in the Samples folder on GitHub. http://aka.ms/template10. What you are asking is not uncommon, neither is it complex. I think reviewing the sample you will see how you need to construct your XAML.

[image]

Comment: Please tell how back button handling can be provided.

Comment: Ask a new question so other developers can benefit.